# Sharing google oauth verification code between android client and rails server

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to setup a sign in via google+ within our mobile app.

So we have a Android client that fetchs a verification code for the oauth google api.

It then sends the verification_code back to rails and rails is responsible for getting the access token / refresh token pair and then talking to the api.

I'm having issue with validation the verification_code.

At first it would return

```
{
  "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch"
}
```

So after reading a bit it seems that we should not specify a redirect_uri for android tokens but when I try to set redirect_uri to nil it fails with

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Missing parameter: redirect_uri"
}
```

I also tried by setting it to an empty string instead of nil and got the uri_mismatch again.

I tried to do a regular auth with a verification code obtained with the oauth playground and it works from there.

A bit of code

```
@authorization = CLIENT_SECRETS.to_authorization
@authorization.clear_credentials!
@authorization.grant_type = 'authorization_code'
@authorization.code = authorization_code
@authorization.redirect_uri = nil
@authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so actually it was kinda of hidden but I found it.

So you need to set the redirect uri to the "out of band" uri set up within the credentials.

```
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

The Client doesn't actually sets it to that value but I guess google defaults it to it.

The current signet gem does not allow redirect_uri to be set to that value so I added a PR to the main repo, In the mean time I'm using my fork and it works fine.

https://github.com/google/signet/pull/35

Answer (score 0):

The Redirect URIs you send needs to match the one that you have set up in [google apis console](https://cloud.google.com/console).

APIs & auth -> credentials